# GoWorkers how to store logs into a file

Tags: go

How can I store the logs which are coming from GoWorkers ([docs](http://godoc.org/github.com/jrallison/go-workers#WorkersLogger)) into a file. I show that there is a `WorkersLogger` interface but I don't understand how to use it.

At the moment I have this:

```
func main() {
  workers.Configure(map[string]string)
  workers.Middleware.Append(&midRetry{})
  workers.Process("imp", worker.InitJob, 30)
  workers.Run()
}

type midRetry struct{}
func (r *midRetry) Call(queue string, message *workers.Msg, next func() bool) (acknowledge bool) {
  acknowledge = next()
  return
}
```

I was thinking in creating a `chan string` in the midRetry struct, and inside Call send messages on the channel, and receive them in main, and then write them to file, but I feel that there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WorkerLogger` interface is just an interface for a struct that implements the `Println` and `Printf` methods.

You can simply define a new `log.Logger`, give it an `os.File` as output ([see the constructor](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#New)), and set the global var `workers.Logger` to this new logger.

Example:

```
file, _ := os.Create("log.txt")
workers.Logger = log.New(file, "[worker] ", log.LstdFlags)
```

Comment: can you give me a example please.